# How to get an event ID from the HitID returned by a Microsoft Graph search query?

Tags: events, search, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to patch a calendar event with the Microsoft Graph API (from a Node express app).

1. I create a new event with `client.api('/me/events').post(myEvent)` and it works just fine (I see it appear in my calendar). The return value has an ID which is:

`AAMkADc0Yjg2ODdmLTlkNDQtNGQ0Yi1iNjBmLTE1MDdmYzI4MGJkOABGAAAAAADt0ZJy6xMCRq23C8icFGeqBwAOM3XMH4d2SYMQ5psbvFytAAAAAAENAAAOM3XMH4d2SYMQ5psbvFytAAJ_B-B7AAA=`

2. I then use `client.api('/search/query').post(myQuery)` to find the event based on some criteria, and this works fine. I receive an array of hits, with only one hit (which actually is the freshly created event, looking at the subject and body), and with a `hitId` equal to:

`AAMkADc0Yjg2ODdmLTlkNDQtNGQ0Yi1iNjBmLTE1MDdmYzI4MGJkOABGAAAAAADt0ZJy6xMCRq23C8icFGeqBwAOM3XMH4d2SYMQ5psbvFytAAAAAAENAAAOM3XMH4d2SYMQ5psbvFytAAJ+B/B7AAA=`

For some reason I don't understand why the 2 IDs are not fully identical: the `_` is changed to `+`and `-`changed to `/`.

3. I now want to modify the event, and try to update it with

```
let newVal = hits[0].resource // hits is coming from the result returned by the search query
newVal.id = hits[0].hitId // needed because the 'resource' does not contain the id
client.api('/me/events/'+hitId).patch(newVal)
```

But I get an error: `Resource not found for the segment 'B7AAA='.`

Could you please tell me how to make the patch work (and explain why the ID from the search is not strictly like the one created). I have read several examples in the documentation (such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-events) but I could not find a solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the create event and the search events apis on [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and seen the same behaviour with ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is happening here is, `PATCH /me/events/{hitId}` is being resolved by Graph API such that the forward slash in the `hitId` denotes a path and Graph ends up using `B7AAA=` as a resource id hence the error `Resource not found for the segment 'B7AAA='.`

A work around that might work is to replace `/` in `hitId`(s) with `%252F`. You can do it like this.

```
client.api(`/me/events/${hitId.replace('/', '%252F')}`).patch(patch)
```

There is already this [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10167) for documentation on how to handled these base64 encoded resource ids with `/`

As for the two IDs being non identical, Graph API will accept both of them and resolve to the same resource. I have no idea why they are different though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes me understand the error. I have added the "replace", however with my new tests today, I no longer have a "/" in the ID, so it now works. Let's see the next time I have a "/" in an ID, or a "+". However how to safely handle the transformation of "_" to "+", and any other possible change in the value retrieved by the query?

Comment: Actually, you are not supposed to do the dirty work of transforming between these characters. Graph should accept the id received from the API. In the case of `/` it should handle the escape encoding as a single `%2F`. Thats why this issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10167 exists.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please accept so that other user with similar question will get help too.