# issue with Microsoft graph api with forward slashes "/" in /me/events/{id}

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am having a similar issue to the post described here.

[How to get an event ID from the HitID returned by a Microsoft Graph search query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984323/how-to-get-an-event-id-from-the-hitid-returned-by-a-microsoft-graph-search-query)

In my case I am not trying to do a patch, but just a lookup via the v1.0/me/events/{id} get request.  I am using the search API of Microsoft graph API.  It returns me a HitId with forward slashes in it.  I tried to resolve it in the exact same way as the post describes, but cant seem to get it to work.  My id parameter is:

AAMkADgwZjlhNmJjLWNiMGQtNGE5MS1hMDVkLTNkNTU2ZWE5ZmM5ZgBGAAAAAAAjq0f6CrWJSoJ6oKcYbrJfBwAyr2CWzX9CSrX7fgfr1AFOAAAAAAENAAAyr2CWzX9CSrX7fgfr1AFOAAV/rENQAAA=

I replaced the / with %252F and the call still fails.  The new request id is:

AAMkADgwZjlhNmJjLWNiMGQtNGE5MS1hMDVkLTNkNTU2ZWE5ZmM5ZgBGAAAAAAAjq0f6CrWJSoJ6oKcYbrJfBwAyr2CWzX9CSrX7fgfr1AFOAAAAAAENAAAyr2CWzX9CSrX7fgfr1AFOAAV%252FrENQAAA=

which still fails in exactly the same way.  To isolate the problem I used Microsoft Graph API explorer to test the request, which returns the following error message

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'rENQAAA='.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-03-18T07:48:24",
            "request-id": "83cecc8b-f510-4cf0-b5f1-e4cd5f09e223",
            "client-request-id": "530677e9-fa2d-a842-149e-a8db4939f3b8"
        }
    }
}
```

I cant seem to find any suitable documentation on how to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where ever you get `/` simply replace it with `-`. that resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Ill try that right now.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: that worked perfectly. Thank you for the help

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Moving this to answer.

Comment: Please accept it so that it could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where ever you get `/` simply replace it with `-`. This will resolve your issue.